# LibGDX - Loading Objectmap, which is saved within another Objectmap

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I'm using Eclipse with LibGDX and I want to reate savefiles for my game. Actually I am able to create a simble JSON file and read it out. For single Objects this works fine, but in my game the objects hold other objects, which hold other ones an so on. And every object has multple values, like xpos, ypos, health ... 
For tests I used new classes. I have the Class SaveDataChunk, which contains an int, a string and an Object from the Class 'Item'. Item itself contains 3 ints, va, vb and vc. For creating and loading from JSON file I used the code from [Toxsick Producctions](http://www.toxsickproductions.com/libgdx/libgdx-intermediate-saving-and-loading-data-from-files/)
I modified it a bit to this code:

```
public class SaveManager {

private boolean encoded;
public FileHandle file = Gdx.files.absolute(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath().concat("bin/world1.json"));
private Save save;

public SaveManager(boolean encoded){
    this.encoded = encoded;
    save = getSave();
}

public static class Save{
    public ObjectMap<String, Object> data = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
}

private Save getSave(){
    Save lsave = new Save();

    if(file.exists()){
        Json json = new Json();
        if(encoded){
            lsave = json.fromJson(Save.class, Base64Coder.decodeString(file.readString()));
        }else{
            lsave = json.fromJson(Save.class, file.readString());
        }
    }else{
        saveToJson(lsave);
    }
    return lsave;
}

public void saveToJson(Object pObj){
    Json json = new Json();
    json.setOutputType(OutputType.json);
    if(encoded){
        file.writeString(Base64Coder.encodeString(json.prettyPrint(pObj)), false);
    }else{
        file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(pObj), false);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public  <T> T loadDataValue(String key, Class type){
    save = getSave();
    if(save.data.containsKey(key)){
        return (T) save.data.get(key);
    }else{
        return null;   //this if() avoids and exception, but check for null on load.
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public  <T> T loadDataValue(String key, Class type, ObjectMap<String, Object> jsonfile){
    if(jsonfile.containsKey(key)){
        return (T) jsonfile.get(key);
    }else{
        return null;   //this if() avoids and exception, but check for null on load.
    }
}

public void saveDataValue(String key, Object object){
    save = getSave();
    save.data.put(key, object);
    saveToJson(save); //Saves current save immediatly.
}

public ObjectMap<String, Object> getAllData(){
    save = getSave();
    return save.data;
}

public boolean isEncoded(){
    return encoded;
}

public void setFileName(String s){
    file = Gdx.files.absolute(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath().concat("bin/" + s + ".json"));
}
```

}

My Save method looks like this:

```
private void saveData() { //TODO
    SaveDataChunk sdc = new SaveDataChunk();
    sdc.setS("hallo! random number: " + random(7, 13));
    sdc.setA((int)random(1, 3));
    saveManager.saveDataValue("AllTheData", sdc.getJsonData());
}
```

SaveDataChunk's method:

```
public ObjectMap<String, Object> getJsonData(){
    ObjectMap<String, Object> mydata = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
    mydata.put("a", a);
    mydata.put("s", s);
    mydata.put("item", item.getJsonData());
    return mydata;
}
```

Item's method:

```
public ObjectMap<String, Object> getJsonData(){
    ObjectMap<String, Object> mydata = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
    mydata.put("va", va);
    mydata.put("vb", vb);
    mydata.put("vc", vc);
    return mydata;
}
```

The load-method:

```
private void loadData() { //TODO
    ObjectMap<String, Object> localdata  = saveManager.loadDataValue("AllTheData", null);
    Array<String> keys = localdata.keys().toArray();
}
```

A possible Json file looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "AllTheData": {
      "class": "com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ObjectMap",
      "a": {
        "class": "java.lang.Integer",
        "value": 2
      },
      "item": {
        "va": {
          "class": "java.lang.Integer",
          "value": 1
        },
        "vb": {
          "class": "java.lang.Integer",
          "value": 2
        },
        "vc": {
          "class": "java.lang.Integer",
          "value": 3
        }
      },
      "s": {
        "class": "java.lang.String",
        "value": "hallo! random number: 9.828029"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The actual problem:
I can load an Objectmap (localdata) and display all the keys (a,s,item). I can also save just the item's data with this:

```
saveManager.saveDataValue("AllTheData", sdc.getItem().getJsonData());
```

This works and I get a list which conaints just the 3 ints of the item. And this is exactly the list i want to load from the sdc.
I'm using "localdata.get(keys.get(0))" to get an item of the objectmap and it works fine with the int (a) and String (s). I can also get the item, but I want to have access to the ints within the item, so i want that objectmap which is in the first one and that's where I fail. I tried different types of casting, but I got always errors because it was not possible to cast.

Has someone an idea how to fix this or do you know another way of loading this type of jason files?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this exact same problem today and the workaround I used was to wrap the ObjectMap like so.

```
class ObjectMapWrapper{
    public ObjectMap<String, Object> data = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
}
```

Then you can do something like

```
public void save( ObjectMap<String, Object> saveMap ){
    ObjectMapWrapper wrapper = new ObjectMapWrapper();
    ObjectMap<String, Object> mydata = wrapper.data;
    mydata.put("va", va);
    mydata.put("vb", vb);
    mydata.put("vc", vc);

    saveMap.put( "mydata", wrapper );
}
```

or however you want to work it. When you restore from json, the ObjectMapWrapper class will deserialize and cast without problems.

```
ObjectMapWrapper wrapper = (ObjectMapWrapper)saveMap.get("mydata");
```

I'm sure there's probably a correct json way to actually store an ObjectMap within an ObjectMap without resorting to the above hack, but I haven't ploughed into the json doco yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a better way? But this is how i roll...

```
{
  "data": {
    "AllTheData": {
      "class": "com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ObjectMap",
      "a": {
        "class": "java.lang.Integer",
        "value": 2
      },
      "item": {
        "va": {
          "class": "java.lang.Integer",
          "value": 1
        },
        "vb": {
          "class": "java.lang.Integer",
          "value": 2
        },
        "vc": {
          "class": "java.lang.Integer",
          "value": 3
        }
      },
      "s": {
        "class": "java.lang.String",
        "value": "hallo! random number: 9.828029"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.absolute(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath().concat("bin/world1.json"));

JsonValue jsonValue = new JsonReader().parse(file /*Base64Coder.decodeString(file.readString())*/);
JsonValue data = jsonValue.get("data");

JsonValue allTheData = data.get("AllTheData");

int a = allTheData.get("a").get("value").asInt();

int va = allTheData.get("item").get("va").get("value").asInt();
int vb = allTheData.get("item").get("vb").get("value").asInt();
int vc = allTheData.get("item").get("vc").get("value").asInt();

String s = allTheData.get("s").get("value").asString();
```